# Show that the relation is transitive?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

> Let $A=(1,2,3,4,5,6)$ and let $S=P(A)$, the power set of $A$.
>
> For $a,b\in S$, define $a\sim b$ if $a$ and $b$ have the same number of elements. Prove that $\sim$ defines an equivalence relation on $S$.

So I figured out how to prove that it was reflexive and symmetric, but am unsure how to prove that its transitive.

Comment: If $|a|=|b|$ and $|b|=|c|$ what can you say about $|a|$ and $|c|$ ?

Comment: I understand the concept, you would be able to say that they too are equal, I am just having trouble applying it to this particular example.